# Wronskian and Linear Dependence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

> Let $y_1$, $y_2$ be two solutions of a homogeneous linear second order differential equation $y''$ + $p(t)y'$ + $q(t)y$ = $0$ over the interval $\alpha$ < $t$ < $\beta$.
>
> Prove that the wronskian $W[y_1, y_2]$ := $y_1y_2'$ - $y_1'y_2$ is zero or nonzero over the whole interval $\alpha$ < $t$ < $\beta$, that is, if $W$ is zero(respectiely nonzero) at one point $t_0$ in the interval $\alpha$ < $t$ < $\beta$, then $W$ should be zero(respectively nonzero) on all points in the interval.

I saw this problem on my book, and I have no idea how to approach. I know that $W[y_1, y_2] = 0$ means that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly dependent, and I think we should use this fact, but how? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$
W'= y_1'y_2'+y_1y_2''-y_1''y_2-y_1'y_2'=y_1y_2''-y_1''y_2 \\
=y_1(-p(t)y_2'-q(t)y_2)-y_2(-p(t)y_1'-q(t)y_1)=-p(t)W
$$

Comment: By the statement you wrote, we know that W(t) = C*exp(...), so if W(t) is zero at some point then it means that C is zero and then we can conclude that W(t) is zero over the whole interval. Is it right? And then I can apply the same thing to the nonzero-case.

Comment: @AABBCC:  That is correct!